# ExpressJS doesn't wait for my promise

Tags: javascript, express

I'm making a search-page on my server. When the endpoint is reached and the user waits for the search function to return the results and render the page Express falls through to the 404 handler instead, and I get the following error when I suppose the render function is called:

*Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.*

What am I doing wrong?

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const queryString = req.query.q;

        const user = helper.checkAndGetUser(req, res);

        let s = String(queryString), searchedTags = [""];
        if(s.indexOf(",") > -1){
            searchedTags = s.replace(" ", "").split(",");
        }

        const options = {
            "query": {tags: {$all: searchedTags}, _forSale: true}
        };

        const results = await Search.search(options).then(result => result).catch(err => {
            throw err;
        });

        //This res.render -call is called after the 404 splat-route.
        return res.render("partial/search.pug", {user: user, search: {
            query: queryString,
            results: results
        }});

        //If I'd use res.send for debugging, it is instead called before the splat-route, like the following:
        return res.send(results);
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I register the router:

```
const search = require("./search.js");
app.use("/search", search);
```

Followed by the 404 splat-route:

```
app.get("*", async (req, res, next) => {

    const user = helper.checkAndGetUser(req, res);

    res.status(404);
    res.render("partial/404.pug", {user: user});
});
```

To clarify:
My question is how can I make the res.render function get called just as the res.send function?

**UPDATE [2017-10-05]:**
I continued with another part of the site, a similar endpoint, and discovered that sending the result provided by the promise worked as expected if using res.send but not res.render. Using res.render the 404-handler kicked in again. Can this be a bug in Express?

Comment: Express will wait for your promise, but it looks like you (1) might not be catching it, or (2), your promise resolves but you are getting an excepting by sending bad data to your `render` method. Make sure `user`, `queryString`, etc, exist.

Comment: I've double checked that those two variables exist and contain valid data, by loggin their content, which gets called every request. Just before the error, as expected. So this prove that the promise resolves. Can you explain what you mean by (1)?

Comment: I need to see more code. That 404 handler should just be a splat route after all your other routes to "catch all that dont match" `app.get('*', (req) => { res.render('404', { req }) })`

Comment: What part do you want to see? The other routes or the logic?

Comment: Even just the functions with nothing in them, contrived names if you want. I want to see how the logic can potentially act during this flow. im in a meeting right now getting yelled at if i am typing, give me a bit >_<. i'd like to see more around the `Search.search()` part, before/after, anything in iteresting?

Comment: I've added the code before the Search function, which is the last thing in the  endpoint.

Comment: We can probably fix it with (starting with) async await: `router.get("/", async (req, res) => {` and `await Search.search(...)` but I'd like to speak to your error handling architecture.

Comment: As of now I'm only pushing errors to the top of the stack via callbacks or promises, where I handle them.

Comment: The short answer is your error handler middleware is running first, and allowing the route to still process, so it sets the header again in the route after it already sent 404.

Comment: Yes, I'm with you on that. There's not really much logic in the error-handler, I'll update the code above. That whole block is just placed beneath all other routers.

Comment: I edited my answer just in case you didnt see it. Let me know if that allows you to see a viable solution.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll apply it to my code and try it tomorrow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few days of going through the code again and again I stumbled upon a problem in the checkAndGetUser-function, that when run without the user being signed in, and since it's faster than the async call to the DB,  triggered the splat endpoint and thus showed the 404 page.

I believe the reason for not triggering the splat endpoint when the res.render call was replaced by res.send was that the res.send function is that much faster than the render-call, since it doesn't have to parse any HTML.

Thank you @agm1984 for providing very useful information about the Express framework, if anyone else are having the same or a similar problem, make sure to read through his post.

Answer (score 4):

This happens if you attempt to write to `res` after it is sent, so you must be calling additional code after `res.render()` or you already responded before calling that.

change it to `return res.render(...)` so it exits the functions, otherwise it will continue through the function and hit other `res.render()`s etc.

Something is up with that error handler also. I will update my post in a few mins with tips (on phone). It should probably have `(req, res, next)` and call `return next(err)` and pass it to your error handling middleware.

Here is the pattern I like to use in async/await Express:

```
// these routes occur in the order I show them

app.get('/route', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = 'asdf'
        const payload = await something(data)
            .then((result) => createPayload(result))

        // remember, if you throw anywhere in try block, it will send to catch block
        // const something = willFail().catch((error) => {
        //     throw 'Custom error message:' + error.message
        // })

        // return from the route so nothing else is fired
        return res.render('route', { payload })
    } catch (e) {
        // fire down to error middleware
        return next(e)
    }
})

// SPLAT
app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
    // if no matching routes, return 404
    return res.status(404).render('error/404')
})

// ERRORS
app.use(async (err, req, res, next) => {
    // if err !== null, this middleware fires
    // it has a 4th input param "err"
    res.status(500).render('error/500')
    // and do whatever else after...
    throw err
})
```

> **Note**: `next()` callback called without param is treated as no error, and proceeds to the next middleware. If `anything` is passed in, it will fire the error middleware with the param as the value of `err` in the error handling middleware. You can use this technique in routes and other middlewares, as long as the error middleware comes last. Mind your use of `return` with `res.send/render()` to prevent double setting headers.

NEW:

Something looks a little bit off with that `.then()` having a callback in it. I don't see logically where `err` would come from since the value of the resolved promise goes into the `.then()` function as `result`. At this point, it is suspect and should be removed or refactored if possible. This part here:

```
try {
    let results = [];
    await Search.search(options).then(result => {
        results = result;
    }, err => {
        throw err;
    });

    console.log("res.render");
    return res.render("partial/search.pug", {user: user, search: {
        query: string,
        results: results
    }});
} catch(err) {
    next(err);
}
```

First, here is about what I would expect to see with async/await syntax:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        const queryString = req.query.q;
        const user = helper.checkAndGetUser(req, res);

        let s = String(queryString), searchedTags = [""];
        if (s.indexOf(",") > -1) {
            searchedTags = s.replace(" ", "").split(",");
        }
        const options = {
            "query": { tags: { $all: searchedTags }, _forSale: true }
        };

        // If a promise is ever rejected inside a try block,
        // it passes the error to the catch block.
        // If you handle it properly there, you avoid unhandled promise rejections.

        // Since, we have async in the route function, we can use await
        // we assign the value of Search.search(options) to results.
        // It will not proceed to the render statement
        // until the entire promise chain is resolved.
        // hence, then(data => { return data }) energizes `results`
        const results = await Search.search(options)
            .then(data => data)
            // If any promise in this chain is rejected, this will fire
            // and it will throw the error to the catch block
            // and your catch block should pass it through to your
            // error handling middleware
            .catch(err => { throw 'Problem occurred in index route:' + err });

        return res.render("partial/search.pug", {
            user: user, search: {
                query: string,
                results: results
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // look at the top how we added next as the 3rd, callback parameter
        return next(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Error handler:

```
// notice how we add `err` as first parameter
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

    const user = helper.checkAndGetUser(req, res);

    res.status(404);
    res.render("partial/404.pug", {user: user});
});
```

From the Express docs:

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three: (err, req, res, next). For example:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

That might be your true issue because the error handler should **only** fire if `next()` is called with **any** input, but yours appears to be firing every time like a normal middleware, so I suspect it's because there is no `err` parameter on that middleware function, so it is treated as a normal one.

> **The Default Error Handler**
>
> Express comes with a built-in error handler, which takes care of any errors that might be encountered in the app. This default error-handling middleware function is added at the end of the middleware function stack.
>
> If you pass an error to next() and you do not handle it in an error handler, it will be handled by the built-in error handler; the error will be written to the client with the stack trace. The stack trace is not included in the production environment.
>
> If you call next() with an error after you have started writing the response (for example, if you encounter an error while streaming the response to the client) the Express default error handler closes the connection and fails the request.
>
> So when you add a custom error handler, you will want to delegate to the default error handling mechanisms in Express, when the headers have already been sent to the client:

```
// code example in docs
```

> Note that the default error handler can get triggered if you call next() with an error in your code more than once, even if custom error handling middleware is in place.

I also recommend using that splat route `app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {})` right above the error handler middlware (aka as the **last** loaded route in your list). This will catch all unmatched routes, such as /sih8df7h6so8d7f and forward the client to your 404. I think the error handler middlware is more suited for error 500 and clean formatted type errors because it gives you a function that can parse the value of `next(err)` anytime it is called from a route.

I usually do this for authentication failures with JSON web token (as the first line of code inside every auth required route):

```
if (!req.person) return res.status(403).render('error/403')
```

I realize some of this may `fry your wig wholesale`, so try all this stuff out and see each piece working before you determine if you would like to utilize it or not.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the problem. I know this is the reason I get the error. It's the 404-handler that sends the unwanted response to res. My question is how can I avoid the 404-handler being called and instead make Express wait for my promise to return?

Comment: The error stems from the area in `//Some logic here` if `res.render()` in your example code triggers the error.

Comment: or the error handler is firing also. That could cause it too.

Comment: The error handler, that is the second function in the returned promise, isn't called. And the logic works just fine, otherwise the 'result' parameter wouldn't contain the correct data.

Comment: I agree about handling the error properly, but you shouldn't ever have to `return` the `res` middleware. Be careful of "returning" in Node/Express middleware, since it is a single-threaded async process.

Comment: True, sorry im half here. It needs to call `next(err)` to an error middleware at the *bottom/after* your routes.

Comment: Thank you, although the 404-handler is still run before the render-call.

Comment: I added significant data to my answer starting at `NEW:`

Comment: JohnnyCoder's warning above is true whenever working with promises because when you return inside a `.then()` function using async/await syntax, it resolves the promise, which sends the value back up the chain. In my newest example where I show `const results = await ...`, you can use `return res.render()` or `return next(err)` because it will resolve the promise of the route itself. It's a matter of what promise are you resolving, which async/await can make a bit difficult to understand since it abstracts the logic behind the scenes.

Comment: But, I think your true issue is you are using the error handler middleware as a normal middleware, so it is probably firing before the index route even fires. (because it doesn't have the 1st parameter as `err`).

Comment: Okay, so I followed your guide. I must have gotten the promise's .then() method wrong. I already have the error-handling middleware in my main controller, just before the splat route. However, that splat-route is still firing before the render call. I tried comment it out but then I got a "TypeError: req.next is not a function" on the render-call instead. I really appreciate the time you've put into this, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not the default error handler that's getting called while waiting for the promise to resolve, it's the splat-route.

Comment: The splat route must somehow be loaded in your app before the other routes. You have to mind the order they are loaded. Express moves top to bottom, or left to right, so if you load an array of routes, it needs to get parsed last. With route matching, your API responds with the first matching route, so the only way `app.get('*')` could respond is if it is defined before `app.get('/')`.

Comment: And, `req.next` is not a function, most likely, because it is not defined in the route function. Check to make sure that any route that calls `next()` also has it as the 3rd parameter of the route function, ie: `(req, res, next)`. The Express docs have a section about `next` that explains how it works. Those docs are also extremely good, so I encourage you to literally read the whole thing sometime. You will learn all kinds of sweet tricks.

Comment: Well, I do have the splat-route at the bottom of the file, just above the error-handler. The root-route works, but that route hasn't got anything asynchronous implemented yet. These other two routes, which do have asynchronous logic, doesn't work. I can't understand how that's even possible. Especially since res.send in the exactly same context as res.render is getting fired before the splat-route. See the code in the original post.

Comment: Hmm, it might be working correctly. Your res.render has this in it as it passes the object into the view, `query: string,`. I don't see anything called `string`, so it could be throwing an error. It's not a flow problem in that index route. Remember, if anything fails, it will be thrown into the catch block. put in the catch block `console.log(e)` so you can see what it is. The lack of return keyword in that catch block is also *possibly* contributing.

Comment: You have to consider how the middlewares are working. They all run before every request in the order they are defined, unless you stop them or tell them to ignore. So for yours to be acting strange, it can only be a flow problem or something is executing when you don't expect (which is a more specific flow problem). After middleware's, the routes are defined and examined in the order they are defined, and if no match, your splat route picks it up, and finally, your error handler middleware is defined.

Comment: I recomend putting `console.log('this is firing first')` and `console.log('this is firing second')` and just look at the order they are firing. This should help you quite a bit because you will see what runs right before it blows up. :)

Comment: Also, comment out all your code inside the routes, affected middlewares, and error handler and add it back in line by line and you will see the problem.

Comment: Ok, I will try all your suggestions, although it doesn't look very promising. I once again logged the flow to be sure and it looks like this:
    `Awaiting promise`
    `Splat`
    `Promise resolved`
    `Calling res.render`

Comment: That `string` you mentioned as value to the key `query` was a mistake from my part. It should have been saying `queryString`, the variable defined at the top.

Comment: Try `return res.render()` in the splat route and remove `async` from it. It's not necessary in that context. Async functions return promises, and `return` is the same as `resolve(value)` in that context, which may be causing it to act unruly, and you can remove `, next` from it also if it starts working after that since you arent using it.

Comment: I haven't really looked at that `app.use("/search", search);`. If there is a problem as it loads search.js, it could cause your `res.render()` to malfunction and forward that request to your splat route. Check that out as well.